# Push Notification dont pop up

Tags: android, firebase

I created an Android App with Android Studio. Now I want to do push notifications with Google Firebase.

I have everything set up.

Everything is working well.

This is the problem:

When I send a cloud message to my device as a test, it works. However, when I send a cloud message normally, not as a test, nothing happened.

It does work with Android Studio.

It makes no difference if the app is open or closed.

Why does it not work?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Show community what you have done yourself and what problem you encountered. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for inspiration. Try not to ask several question in one time

Comment: Please provide the configuration code you are using for you notification

Answer (score 0):

If use Android upper Oreo. Need setup channel id and configurate him (sound, priority) https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/channels

and after in firebase message add channel id.

Comment: Hey,thanks for that, but that isn right... i take some very old phones like an LG G2 (Android 4.2.2) for testing this.... but it dont work... i test it with 4 phones, nothing...the only one that work is an Samsung Galaxy S6 with android 7.0. this work without any problem, no other Device works.... WHY :O

Comment: In firebase add priority high and sound on